BIOS no longer detects the system on the second drive
I have two SSD drives in my laptop. On one I have a dual boot of Windows with Linux, on the other Linux alone.This standalone Linux worked without a problem, but I didn't use it for a while, and when I tried to boot it, I found that it was not visible from the bios. I have not changed anything in the UEFI itself. I also have the current bios version (Lenovo GKCN65WW, 16.01.2024). The drive on which the problem occurred is a WD Blue SN570 1TB.
I've tried formatting the drive and installing a new distro from bootable USB. It worked, but still nothing new appeared in the bios.This second drive is also visible in ‘Disk management’ from within Windows 11. Also from Windows, I checked for errors using the wmic command, but both drives returned an `OK' status.

“I have not changed anything in the UEFI itself” - You must have since the EFI partition contains that type of information.
